# WCF singleton hosted in windows service. How to auto start WCF without first "touching" the service with client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in windows service.

Currently when the windows service starts i have to "touch" the WCF service with a client to run some long running code in WCF service.

Is it somehow possible to auto start the long running code in WCF service without calling the service with a client?

IIS 7.5 is not an option.

Comment: @oleksii: you can very much also **self-host** a WCF service inside a **Windows service**. "Self-hosted" just means: your own code - **NOT** inside IIS.

Comment: @marc_s thanks, I was not aware about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [`OnStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method for this. It will be triggered once the Windows service gets a START command from OS.

Put your "touch" code (logic) there.

Comment: Is this the best practice? Will the WCF service run until the host is stopped or will it stop at some point? In WCF i have timers that have to run indefinitely. And stop only when such a command is received.